# ListViewItem: how to change List datas to ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, list, listview, listviewitem

I got 3 List (L1,L2,L3) and i want to show them on ListView.But i cant add or convert, List data's to ListViewItem.Something like this

```
    List<string> for96 = new List<string>();
    List<string> for97 = new List<string>();
    List<string> for98 = new List<string>();
    ListView lv1=new ListView();
    ListViewItem lvitem = new ListViewItem();
    lvitem.Text=for96;
    lvitem.items.add(97);
    lvitem.items.add(98);
    lv1.items.add(lvitem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a variety of routes with this, but here's one possibility.

Join the three lists of strings together and then set that as the data source for your `ListView`:

```
var combinedLists = for96.Union(for97).Union(for98).ToList();

listView.ItemsSource = combinedLists;
```

Comment: i got 3 coloumn on listview its not usefull to combine them..